Uncurling, cleaning and archiving old photos (1930s to 1980s)
My cousin found some old family photos deemed lost (around 400 pieces), spanning 50 years (1930s to 1980s). They've been sitting in a shoebox for over 25 years, in a basement (classic story, right...). Their condition is acceptable, no visible mold/fungus or damage, but smell very musty and are badly curled (I'm guessing both from drying out with time and from the damp/dry cycles in the basement.
The photos are now in my possession as the recognized family historian and I plan to clean, digitize and conserve them. I'm not in the US and professional restoration/conservation services are not readily available, but still, there are local experts that I plan to contact and ask for guidance, too. However, any experience shared would be invaluable to me.
Found two great (in my opinion) articles online about uncurling and cleaning moldy photos
Now, here is the tricky part - to uncurl the photos, I must introduce moisture (otherwise the substrate will crack if only using pressure). And Fungi love moisture, so my plan is to clean both sides of the photos first, curled as they are, with a makeup brush, good cleaning pads or microfiber cloth (for lens cleaning) and a "safe" cleaning solution (PEC-12/Tetenal/Isopropyl Alcohol?)
Then, uncurl them following the method from the first article - laying the photos on one of those desktop document organizer (with stacked mesh trays) and placing it in a closed plastic box with some water on the bottom for 1-3 hours until the photos relax. Once that's done, I'll layer them without overlapping between sheets of glassine or other acid-free paper, pressing them for 24-48 hours with something heavy on top. Once that's done, I plan to bring them out in the sun for 20 minutes per side and finally clean them once again with a cleaning solution before scanning and digitally restoring them (an area I'm well-versed in).
Does that sound like a good plan? Cleaning them without damaging them further, and preventing spore germination and regrowth while uncurling them is what concerns me the most. Also, is the UV-step even needed if mold is ubiquitous and controlling the environment is what matters the most? Do I need acid-free paper while uncurling them or could I use freezer/parchment/baking paper for shorter durations (all three are manufactures using acid and are not acid-free, but the first article mentions freezer paper, hence the question)
Now, the last step, conservation, is where I know next to nothing about. Only that I must use acid-free paper. But how would you go about storing the photos long-term? Bear in mind that they'll be archived for good and placing them in an album for viewing is not needed - I'll make copies that will serve that purpose. But an album sounds like a good way to keep them flat.

Why would you hope for a technical Answer here, rather than in WWW pages devoted to Photography?

The SAR Research Library in Louisville, KY has a Preservation Station with archivists ready to answer questions such as yours. You don't need to be a member of SAR to use their services. If you don't live nearby, the library offers their preservation services for a fee online.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Seems pretty clear to me
